# Prove that the polynomial $p(x) = x^4 - 5x^3 + 3x - 2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I have proved that $p$ has no rational roots. Then I suppose that it factor in two quadratic polynomials $x^2 + ax + b, x^2 + cx + d$ to get a contradiction, but the system is hard. I think that there is an easy method to proof it.

Comment: What about Eisenstein's criterion? Have you done that yet?

Comment: Assume $b= \pm 1, d = \mp 2$.  That should simplify the system considerably.

Comment: You also know that $a+c=-5$ and that $\pm c \mp 2a = 3$.  That limits you to very few choices for $a, c.$  You can then test those choices to confirm that the product doesn't result in a vanishing quadratic term.

Comment: @RobertShore The fact that $b, d\in \mathbb Z$ comes from Gauss - that needs quoting, I think, to justify an integer factorisation.

Comment: From an advanced standpoint, @MattSamuel, Eisenstein only works to show irreducibility when the associated field extension is “totally ramified” above the chosen prime $p$. For extensions of large degree, you don’t expect that, so you should count yourself lucky when Eisenstein works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have checked that $p$ has no rational roots, and therefore no roots in $\Bbb Z$, the ring of integers.

You have correctly concluded that the only possible $\Bbb Z$-factorization is as the product of two quadratics.

However, reading $p$ modulo $2$, we have $p(x)=x(x^3+x^2+1)$ as a polynomial over the field $\Bbb F_2$ with two elements. The second factor is $\Bbb F_2$-irreducible. Uniqueness of factorization in $\Bbb F_2[x]$ says that the *only* $\Bbb F_2$-factorization of $p$ is a linear times an irreducible cubic.

We’re done, for:

If there were a $\Bbb Z$-factorization of $p$ as product of two quadratics, this would go over to a factorization over $\Bbb F_2$ as a product of two quadratics. But there is no such $\Bbb F_2$-factorization, irrespective of reducibility of the quadratic factors.

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb F_{11}$ and hence also over $\Bbb Q$. This is a bit easier to show with the equations, but still some work.

Comment: For checking the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb F$$_{11}$ you use Eisenstein's criterion with $p = 2$?

Comment: Eisenstein can not be used when the coefficients are from a finite field.

Comment: @OriolSors No, I suppose that the polynomial is equal to $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and solve the resulting linear equations modulo $11$. This is not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The equations amount to solving
$$\tag1 a+c=-5,\quad b+d+ac=0,\quad bc+ad=3,\quad bd=-2$$
in integers.

The last eqution amounts to that one of $b,d$ is $\pm1$ and the other is $\mp2$. 
Then $b+d=\pm1$, hence $ac=1$, $a,c\in\{-1,1\}$, contradicting $a+c=-5$.

Apparently we can generalize: All
$$ x^4+ux^3+vx-2$$
with $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ and $|u|>2$ are either irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ or have a root in $\{-2,-1,1,2\}$.